# How to remove outline with img tag in Outlook application

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email, email-templates

> **I'm having an issue with the outlook application.
> One thin line shows above and below the img tag.  I have highlighted
> the line in the screenshot.**

I have attached the screenshot in which the thin line is highlighted.

Please let me know the suggested fix.
Thank you in advance.

[image]

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 639px) {
  .st-title-wrapper {
    padding-left: 50px !important;
    padding-right: 50px !important;
  }
  .st-title {
    font-size: 24px !important;
    line-height: 22px !important;
  }
  .st-desc {
    font-size: 16px !important;
    line-height: 18px !important;
  }
  .footer-links {
    padding-left: 20px !important;
  }
  .footer-link-single {
    padding: 8px 5px !important;
  }
  .footer-link-single a {
    font-size: 14px !important;
  }
  .footer-link-top {
    height: 30px !important;
  }
  .footer-link-bottom {
    height: 30px !important;
  }
  .footer-social {
    padding-top: 32px !important;
    padding-bottom: 32px !important;
  }
  .footer-logo {
    width: 125px !important;
  }
  .footer-logo img {
    width: 125px !important;
  }
}

a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
  color: inherit !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  font-size: inherit !important;
  font-family: inherit !important;
  font-weight: inherit !important;
  line-height: inherit !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
  <title>Email template</title>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting" />
  <!--[if gt mso 15]>
      <style type="text/css" media="all">
        /* Outlook 2016 Height Fix */
        table,
        tr,
        td {
          border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        tr {
          font-size: 0px;
          line-height: 0px;
          border-collapse: collapse;
        }
      </style>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body style="margin: 0">
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td style="max-width: 100%; width: 840px">
          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="background-color: #000">
                          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td style="width: 360px; text-align: center" class="st-title-wrapper">
                                  <font style="
                                        color: #e4002b;
                                        font-family: 'Oswald', Arial, sans-serif;
                                        font-weight: 600;
                                        font-size: 32px;
                                        line-height: 28px;
                                      " class="st-title">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
                                  </font>
                                </td>
                                <td></td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center" bgcolor="#e6e6e6">
                          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse">
                            <tr>
                              <td>
                                <img src="https://rahulshahui.github.io/pwa/images/shape-top.png" width="100%" style="display: block" />
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td align="center" style="padding: 13px 20px">
                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse">
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td></td>
                                      <td width="550" style="text-align: center">
                                        <font style="
                                              color: #1a1a1a;
                                              text-align: center;
                                              font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                                              font-weight: 500;
                                              font-size: 18px;
                                              line-height: 20px;
                                            " class="st-desc">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney
                                          College in Virginia.
                                        </font>
                                      </td>
                                      <td></td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td>
                                <img src="https://rahulshahui.github.io/pwa/images/shape-bottom.png" width="100%" style="display: block" />
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="background-color: #000">
                          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="
                                border-collapse: collapse;
                                border-spacing: 0px;
                              ">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td align="" class="footer-links" style="padding-left: 80px">
                                  <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tbody>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td width="240" valign="top">
                                          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                            <tr>
                                              <td align="" valign="middle" style="padding: 8px 0" class="footer-link-single">
                                                <a href="https://www.google.com/" style="
                                                      color: #fff;
                                                      text-decoration: none;
                                                      font-family: Arial,
                                                        sans-serif;
                                                      font-size: 16px;
                                                    ">Link</a
                                                  >
                                                </td>
                                              </tr>
                                              <tr>
                                                <td
                                                  align=""
                                                  valign="middle"
                                                  style="padding: 8px 0"
                                                  class="footer-link-single"
                                                >
                                                  <a
                                                    href="https://www.google.com/"
                                                    style="
                                                      color: #fff;
                                                      text-decoration: none;
                                                      font-family: Arial,
                                                        sans-serif;
                                                      font-size: 16px;
                                                    "
                                                    >Link</a
                                                  >
                                                </td>
                                              </tr>
                                              <tr>
                                                <td
                                                  align=""
                                                  valign="middle"
                                                  style="padding: 8px 0"
                                                  class="footer-link-single"
                                                >
                                                  <a
                                                    href="https://www.google.com/"
                                                    style="
                                                      color: #fff;
                                                      text-decoration: none;
                                                      font-family: Arial,
                                                        sans-serif;
                                                      font-size: 16px;
                                                    "
                                                    >Link</a
                                                  >
                                                </td>
                                              </tr>
                                              <tr>
                                                <td
                                                  align=""
                                                  valign="middle"
                                                  style="padding: 8px 0"
                                                  class="footer-link-single"
                                                >
                                                  <a
                                                    href="https://www.google.com/"
                                                    style="
                                                      color: #fff;
                                                      text-decoration: none;
                                                      font-family: Arial,
                                                        sans-serif;
                                                      font-size: 16px;
                                                    "
                                                    >Link</a
                                                  >
                                                </td>
                                              </tr>
                                            </table>
                                          </td>
                                          <td width="210" valign="top">
                                            <table
                                              border="0"
                                              cellpadding="0"
                                              cellspacing="0"
                                            >
                                              <tr>
                                                <td
                                                  align=""
                                                  valign="middle"
                                                  style="padding: 8px 0"
                                                  class="footer-link-single"
                                                >
                                                  <a
                                                    href="https://www.google.com/"
                                                    style="
                                                      color: #fff;
                                                      text-decoration: none;
                                                      font-family: Arial,
                                                        sans-serif;
                                                      font-size: 16px;
                                                    "
                                                    >Link</a
                                                  >
                                                </td>
                                              </tr>
                                              <tr>
                                                <td
                                                  align=""
                                                  valign="middle"
                                                  style="padding: 8px 0"
                                                  class="footer-link-single"
                                                >
                                                  <a
                                                    href="https://www.google.com/"
                                                    style="
                                                      color: #fff;
                                                      text-decoration: none;
                                                      font-family: Arial,
                                                        sans-serif;
                                                      font-size: 16px;
                                                    "
                                                    >Link</a
                                                  >
                                                </td>
                                              </tr>
                                              <tr>
                                                <td
                                                  align=""
                                                  valign="middle"
                                                  style="padding: 8px 0"
                                                  class="footer-link-single"
                                                >
                                                  <a
                                                    href="https://www.google.com/"
                                                    style="
                                                      color: #fff;
                                                      text-decoration: none;
                                                      font-family: Arial,
                                                        sans-serif;
                                                      font-size: 16px;
                                                    "
                                                    >Link</a
                                                  >
                                                </td>
                                              </tr>
                                            </table>
                                          </td>
                                        </tr>
                                      </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <table
                              width="100%"
                              border="0"
                              cellspacing="0"
                              cellpadding="0"
                              align="center"
                              style="
                                border-collapse: collapse;
                                border-spacing: 0px;
                              "
                            >
                              <tr>
                                <td
                                  colspan="3"
                                  height="60"
                                  class="footer-link-bottom"
                                ></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td
                                  align="center"
                                  style="
                                    padding-left: 42px;
                                    padding-right: 42px;
                                  "
                                >
                                  <table
                                    width="100%"
                                    border="0"
                                    cellspacing="0"
                                    cellpadding="0"
                                    align="center"
                                    style="
                                      border-collapse: collapse;
                                      border-spacing: 0px;
                                    "
                                  >
                                    <tr>
                                      <td
                                        height="1"
                                        style="background-color: #fff"
                                      ></td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td align="right" colspan="3">
                                  <table
                                    width="100%"
                                    border="0"
                                    cellspacing="0"
                                    cellpadding="0"
                                    align="center"
                                    style="
                                      border-collapse: collapse;
                                      border-spacing: 0px;
                                    "
                                  >
                                    <tr>
                                      <td
                                        align="right"
                                        class="footer-social"
                                        style="
                                          padding-top: 62px;
                                          padding-bottom: 62px;
                                        "
                                      >
                                        <table
                                          border="0"
                                          cellspacing="0"
                                          cellpadding="0"
                                          align="center"
                                          style="
                                            border-collapse: collapse;
                                            border-spacing: 0px;
                                          "
                                        >
                                          <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                              <td
                                                align="center"
                                                valign="middle"
                                                style="
                                                  padding-left: 8px;
                                                  padding-right: 8px;
                                                "
                                              >
                                                <a
                                                  href="https://www.google.com/"
                                                >
                                                  <img
                                                    src="https://rahulshahui.github.io/pwa/images/FB-icon.png"
                                                  />
                                                </a>
                                              </td>
                                            </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

[Below is the code link][2]

```
  [2]: https://codepen.io/rahulFront/pen/oNpPvgZ
```

Comment: Which browser are you using? I don't see these lines in either chrome, safari, or ff. If you are using one of these browsers, please do your best to make sure your snippet produces a [example].

Comment: @Kameron op is writing a mailing which is meant ot be opened by email app Microsoft Outlook in this particular example.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on any version of Outlook (2007-2019 windows desktop, Windows mail, Outlook on Mac, or Outlook.com).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a border.

Try adding `border-width:0;` to the images, e.g.:

`<img src="https://rahulshahui.github.io/pwa/images/shape-bottom.png" width="100%" style="display: block;border-width:0;" />`

Comment: Thanks for reply. 
I have added [border-width:0] in image but still showing the thin line.

Comment: or perhaps use the attribute? I.e. `<img ... style="..." border="0" />`